# Why is my sf::Clock in SFML resetting by itself?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm working on a little SFML game in C++. What I'm trying to do is start the game with an introductory text that flashes two different colors, like "Arturo Girona Presents." I made it work by using a counter that incremented inside the while (window.isOpen()) loop, but then I tried using an sf::Clock to see if it made the flashing look less random. However, for some reason, the clock keeps resetting after each loop when I haven't explicitly told it too, so it's not transitioning from the text screen. How's the clock resetting by itself and how do I fix it?
Here's my while loop:

```
int count = 0;
sf::Clock clock;
int timer = clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();

while (window.isOpen())
{
    count++;
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    while (timer < 5000)
    {
        if (timer < 200 && introText1.getColor() == sf::Color::Red)
        {
            introText1.setColor(sf::Color::White);
            window.draw(introText1);
            window.display();
        }

        if (timer < 200 && introText1.getColor() == sf::Color::White)
        {
            introText1.setColor(sf::Color::Red);
            window.draw(introText1);
            window.display();
        }
        break;
    }
    if (timer == 5000) {
        window.clear();
        window.draw(door);
        window.draw(doorWindow1);
        window.display();
    }

    cout << timer << endl;
    if (timer > 0)
        cout << "Time is moving" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does `cout << timer << endl;` keep showing the same number? You don't seem to have changed this anywhere in the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clock is not being reset, you simply never read the new value. ;-)

Move `int timer = clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();` inside the main loop.

Additionally, you don't want the `while (timer < 5000)` loop especially with a `break` as last statement.

Comment: Thanks! Moving that line solved my problem, but I would have to keep the break; statement or else the program will stop responding  when i run it.

Comment: @ArturoGirona: With that break in there, your `while` is effectively an `if`. It doesn't loop at all. Is that your intention?